# Как правильно синтаксически оформить код?

Tags: php

Как правильно синтаксически оформить следующий кусок кода:

```
<?php
if (<?=$arFields['PROPERTY_STATUS_ID']?> == 141) {
    <span style="color: #5da130;"><?=$arFields['PROPERTY_STATUS_VALUE']?></span>
} elseif (<?=$arFields['PROPERTY_STATUS_ID']?> == 142) {
    <span style="color: #f4c430;"><?=$arFields['PROPERTY_STATUS_VALUE']?></span>
} elseif (<?=$arFields['PROPERTY_STATUS_ID']?> == 143) {
    <span style="color: #ff002e;"><?=$arFields['PROPERTY_STATUS_VALUE']?></span>
}
?>
```

Comment: Удалить Битрикс навсегда!

Comment: @Shrek Плюсую за отгадку!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Синтаксис зависит от принятых соглашений в том или ином фреймворке/движке. Если бы это был Zend, Kohana, Drupal или Joomla, то выглядело бы это всё незначительно по-другому. Мне ближе по стилю Kohana, это бы выглядело так:

```
<?if (intval($arFields['PROPERTY_STATUS_ID']) == 141) :?>
<span style="color: #5da130;">
<?=$arFields['PROPERTY_STATUS_VALUE']?>
</span>
<?elseif (intval($arFields['PROPERTY_STATUS_ID']) == 142) :?>
<span style="color: #f4c430;">
<?=$arFields['PROPERTY_STATUS_VALUE']?>
</span>
<?elseif (intval($arFields['PROPERTY_STATUS_ID']) == 143):?>
<span style="color: #ff002e;">
<?=$arFields['PROPERTY_STATUS_VALUE']?></span>
<?endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если кому интересно, вот решение нашел:

```
<?if (intval($arFields['PROPERTY_STATUS_ID']) == 141) {?>
    <span style="color: #5da130;"><?=$arFields['PROPERTY_STATUS_VALUE']?></span>
<?} elseif (intval($arFields['PROPERTY_STATUS_ID']) == 142){?>
    <span style="color: #f4c430;"><?=$arFields['PROPERTY_STATUS_VALUE']?></span>
<?} elseif (intval($arFields['PROPERTY_STATUS_ID']) == 143){?>
    <span style="color: #ff002e;"><?=$arFields['PROPERTY_STATUS_VALUE']?></span>
<?}?>
```

Comment: Да, на порядок лучше стало. `142.`